# Cortana Integration with Bot Framework

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, bots, artificial-intelligence

I need to integrate cortana with the bot framework. For that i did a research on internet and most of the sites are saying it as "coming soon".

I need to clarify whether it is possible to integrate cortana with bot framework now. If so, can you provide a proper document on how to integrate it. If not possible, could you please let me know when it will be available

Comment: We have no idea about the timelines of other people. You should contact the sites you found and ask them if they have a timeline for Cortana/Bot Framework integration.

Comment: @RobertColumbia i need to know it possible or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has just release Cortana channels for your existing Bot Framework bots at Build 2017.
More detail available here: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/05/10/Build/
Cheers,
Pieter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But that is only available in United States. If you'd like to use your bot, you have to set region to United States.